# Is using pointers in C++ always bad?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I was told to avoid using pointers in C++. It seems that I can't avoid them however in the code i'm trying to write, or perhaps i'm missing out on other great C++ features.

I wish to create a class (class1) which contains another class (class2) as a data member. I then want class2 to know about class1 and be able to communicate with it.

I could have a reference to class1 as a member in class2 but that then means I need to provide a reference to class1 as a parameter in the constructor of class2 and use initialiser lists which I don't want. I'm trying to do this without needing the constructor to do it.

I would like for class2 to have a member function called Initialise which could take in the reference to class1, but this seems impossible without using pointers. What would people recommend here? Thanks in advance.

The code is completely simplified just to get the main idea across :

```
class class1
{
    public:
        InitialiseClass2()
        {
            c2.Initialise(this);
        }

    private:
        class2 c2;

};

class class2
{
    public:
        Initialise(class1* c1)
        {
            this->c1 = c1;
        }

    private:
        class1* c1;

};
```

Comment: Are you asking whether to use references instead of pointers, or whether you should use neither?

Comment: Its raw **owning** pointers which were to avoid.

Comment: pointers are part of C++ and you can't avoid them all the time. Why do you want to avoid constructors and initializer list ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Still, having pointer arithemtic when you don't need it isn't ideal. I'd probably opt for an `std::reference_wrapper<class1>`. Although it might not work with incomplete types...

Comment: See [Why are pointers not recommended when coding with C++?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/163279/2366)

Comment: Should I use references instead of pointers?

Comment: In this case I don't want the construction of class2 to depend on passing a reference to class1. I'd like to use the default constructor and then later pass in the handler to class1

Comment: @Engineer999, should you use spoons insteads of forks? Same kind of question. Pointers are pointers, references are references. They have their own applicability.

Comment: @Engineer999: Seems like a design smell to me. What state is your object in between construction and a call to `Initialize()`? What happens if you perform operations on it in that state?

Comment: i'm starting to work on a big C++ project.. my first one I would say. I was told, do not use pointers in C++. There should be no need. This is the part I don't understand. In order to dynamically create objects on the free-store, don't we need pointers ?

Comment: Of course you need pointers. Try putting references in the container. YOU DO NEED POINTERS in C++ programms. You just do now want to manage them.

Comment: @Engineer999: You're repeating vaguenesses, which isn't particularly helpful, but I shall assume you are asking "don't we need raw pointers, `new` and `delete`?" No. No, you do not. Look up `std::make_unique`. Look up `std::vector`. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: None really. i was reading parts of Stroustrup's 4th edition and stuff online. I think my mind is stuck more in C and embedded systems )). I am fairly new to C++ and perhaps thinking too much about memory etc. when perhaps I should be thinking on a higher level

Comment: You don't need pointers in C++. Never. That's why they were marked deprecated on the standard in 2001. :DDD

Comment: Pointers are used, in the Embedded Systems arena, to access hardware devices.  In this case, raw pointers work a lot better (more efficient) than smart pointers.  Also, there is no "memory" allocated and none to delete.

Answer (score 6):

> this seems impossible without using pointers

That is incorrect. Indeed, to handle a reference to some other object, *take a reference* into a constructor:

```
class class2
{
    public:
        class2(class1& c1)
           : c1(c1)
        {}

    private:
        class1& c1;
};
```

The key here is to initialise, not assign, the reference. Whether this is *possible* depends on whether you can get rid of your `Initialise` function and settle into RAII (please do!). After that, whether this is *actually a good idea* depends on your use case; nowadays, you can almost certainly make ownership and lifetime semantics much clearer by using one of the smart-pointer types instead — even if it's just a `std::weak_ptr`.

Anyway, speaking more generally.

**Are pointers "always" bad?** No, of course not. I'd almost be tempted to say that managing dynamic memory yourself is "always" bad, but I won't make a generalisation.

**Should you *avoid* them?** Yes.

The difference is that the latter is a guideline to steer you away from manual memory management, and the former is an attempted prohibition.

Comment: @Engineer999: With one of the many standard containers at your disposal. Your code will be more maintainable and bug-free if you use those where you can, instead of hacking around with the free store on your own. _That's the purpose of the advice you cite._ And if you want to exclude standard smart pointers from "pointers", there's always `std::make_{unique,shared}` which at least handles pointee lifetime for you. Are there occasions where you will have a good reason to use raw pointers? Yes! Use the right tool for the job. It's just that raw pointers are rarely the right tool for the job.

Comment: plus one from a carnivorous cat

Answer (score 4):

No, using pointers in C++ is not bad at all, and I see this anti-advice over and over again. What is bad is managing pointers by yourself, unless you are creating a pointer-managing low-level entity.

Again, I shall make a very clear distinction. Using pointers is good. Very few real C++ programs can do without USING pointers. Managing pointers is bad, unless you are working on pointer manager.

Comment: “I see this anti-advice over and over again” — really? I don’t. It’s almost exclusively about owning pointers, and then a bit about using references where appropriate. But once that’s taken into account the remaining uses of raw pointers are fairly few (though OP’s might be one).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it is always a confirmation bias :) You have to trust me here, I personally have seen it everywhere, including coding guidelines of one of my former teams.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, even your own answer has the same issue: "modern C++ idioms often don’t need pointers at all" - from your link. Talk to me about non-usage of const char*.

Comment: My own answer is very much in line with my comment above: once you’ve eliminated legacy uses of raw pointers, there are not many remaining uses. Those that remain, however, are of course entirely valid (though, caveat, I’d prefer it if C++ had no privileged syntax for this type of pointers, but rather a class template `raw_ptr` or `address` to represent them). I disagree that my answer has an issue in that way. I’m not sure what you mean by “non-usage of `const char*`”.

Comment: @SergeyA: Perhaps you forgot to read the word "often"? `const char*` is like one of the very few examples of good pointer usage, and even then you could often deem it a microoptimisation in some sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, here we are again. I can keep finding good usages of pointers, and you will keep saying it is not 'often'. Been there, done that. But saying that const char* is not often used... I am not sure what to reply with.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Konrad said 'often don't need'. I mentioned const char*. You said I misread 'often' - implying that const char* is not often? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @SergeyA Incidentally, I think it’s clear that we all agree on the matter. We just disagree (fundamentally, I believe) on the phrasing. Here’s my perspective: this question once again shows how completely badly pointers in C++ are usually taught, resulting in bad, buggy, inefficient code. The way to break this cycle is to take the privileged position away from pointers in C++. Pointers should be thought of as just another type, to be used at discretion and with thought, not as the default go-to type. As a programmer, I use raw pointers where needed. As a teacher, I abhor C++ raw pointer syntax

Comment: @SergeyA: You've completely lost me now but I'm nonetheless fairly sure you misunderstood me and Konrad both.

Comment: How about containers of polymorphic objects? How would you do this without pointers? Not often enough? How about indexes to various heavy-weight object collections? Not often?

Comment: Um, `boost::ptr_{map,vector,etc}`? For an indexed collection wrap a `boost::bimap`.... These are solved problems and do not require pissing about with raw pointers in userspace.

Comment: Well sure, same thing if you think that using `std::vector` is "using pointers". Might as well just go home now

Comment: No, using vector is not using pointer. But using a vector of pointers is using a pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA Good question. Depends on usage. However, I don’t use OOP excessively; recently, I have often used functional ways of implementing polymorphism (tagged unions, i.e. `boost::variant` + visitors), or I encapsulate polymorphic objects into their own memory-managing classes (I think this is sometimes known as envelope–letter pattern?).

Comment: @SergeyA: Then it's a good thing nobody (but you) suggested using a vector of pointers. Using `boost::ptr_vector` is "using pointers" precisely as much as using `std::vector` is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I've been pretty `boost::variant`-heavy lately, too.

Comment: It's a pity you do not know what you are talking about, LRiO. _A ptr_vector<T> is a pointer container that uses an underlying std::vector<void*> to store the pointers._

Comment: Yes, and a `vector<T>` is a data container that uses an underlying region of dynamically allocated memory, accessed through a `T*`, to store the data. The container uses pointers, but that usage is entirely abstracted away from the call site. That's the point. Kind of basic stuff, to be quite honest.

Comment: I am. To put elements into ptr_vector, you need to provide it with POINTERS. Do I need to remind you the prototype for `replace()`? It is accepting pointer, so when you call this function, you are using a pointer. What else?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am not a fan of OOP myself, this is certain. To me the much more relevant example is an index.

Comment: As it seems I can't budge you on your extremely broad definition of "using pointers", let's leave it there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, oh, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157539/graph-structure-are-pointers-bad - another one saying that pointers are bad.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer can be `nullptr` whereas a reference must always be bound to something (and cannot be subsequently re-bound to something else).

That's the chief distinction and the primary consideration for your design choice.

Memory management of pointers can be delegated to `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` as appropriate.

Comment: Just as importantly, a reference cannot rebound once it’s bound. A pointer can.

Comment: but by using only references , then I cannot create objects on the free-store using "new" and "delete" ?

Comment: @Engineer999 You don’t want to do that anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's a good point. If you don't mind, I've plagiarised that.

Comment: While technically accurate I think this answer fails to glance at the real meat of the question.

Comment: Pointers can also point to hardware registers; I have yet to create a reference to a hardware register. :-)

Answer (score 0):

well, I never had the need to 2 classes to have reciprocal reference and for good reasons, how do you know how to test those classes? If later you need to change something in the way the 2 classes communicates you will probably have to change code in both classes). **You can workaround  in many ways**:

1. You may need in reality just 1 class ( you have broken into much classes)
2. You can register a Observer for a class (using a 3rd class, in that case you will end up with a pointer, but at least the 2 classes are less coupled and it is easier test them).
3. You can think (maybe) to a new interface that require only 1 class to call methods on the other class
4. You could pass a lambda (or a functor if you do not have C++11) into one of the methods of the class removing the need to a back reference
5. You could pass a reference of the class inside a method.
6. Maybe you have to few classes and in reality you need a third class than communicates with both classes.
7. It is possible you need a Visitor (maybe you really need multiple dispatch)

Some of the workarounds above need pointers, some not. To you the choice ;)

NOTE: However what you are doing is perfectly fine to me (I see you do some trickery only in constructors, but probably you have more omitted code, in wich case that can cause troubles to you). In my case I "register" one class into another, then after the constructor called I have only one class calling the other and not viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

First of all whenever you have a circular dependency in your design think about it twice and make sure it's the way to go. Try to use the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) in order to analyze and fix your dependencies.

> I was told to avoid using pointers in C++. It seems that I can't avoid them however in the code i'm trying to write, or perhaps i'm missing out on other great C++ features.

Pointers are a powerful programming tool. Like any other feature in the C++ (or in any programming language in general) they have to be used when they are the right tool. In C++ additionally you have access to references which are similar to pointers in usage but with a better syntax. Additionally they can't be null. Thus they always reference a valid object.

So use pointers when you ever need to but try to avoid using **raw** pointers and prefer a smart pointer as alternative whenever possible. This will protect you against some trivial memory leak problems but you still have to pay attention to your object life-cycle and for each dynamically allocated object you should know clearly who create it and when/whom will release the memory allocated for the object.

Pointers (and references) are very useful in general because they could be used to pass parameters to a method *by reference* so you avoid passing heavy objects by value in the stack. Imagine the case for example that you have a very big array of heavy objects (which copy/= operator is time consuming) and you would like to sort these objects. One simple method is to use pointers to these objects so instead of moving the whole object during the sorting operation you just move the pointers which are very lightweight data type (size of machine address basically).